# Cannot merge / delete feature branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have merged a feature branch back onto develop, but it keeps re-appearing when I do a git fetch --all --prune.

The commits from the merged branch also reappear on the merged branch, and the deleted branch is recreated.

What could be causing this behavior?

After merging and deleting feature branch, doing a fetch outputs the following:

Fetching origin
From bitbucket.org:Project/projectName
 + fbfe775...9ad9ec2 develop    -> origin/develop  (forced update)

Notice the "forced update" , this command adds 14 commits to the branch.

The merge is subsequently deleted and the feature branch in quesiton restored as if I had not merged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably still have the branch on the remote server. Run push to delete it:

```
git push origin :name_of_the_branch
```

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch` gets commits—and branch names—from some *other* Git.  It then renames *their* branch names, such as `feature`, to your *remote-tracking names* such as `origin/feature`.

If you delete your own `origin/feature` remote-tracking name, that has no effect on the *other* Git.  Running `git fetch origin` will find that `origin` has a branch named `feature`, and will therefore update-or-create your own `origin/feature`.

What you must do, then, is clear: remove the *branch name* `feature` *from the other Git repository*, so that when your Git connects to their Git, they *don't* have branch name `feature` and your Git *won't* update-or-create your own `origin/feature`, and in fact, with `--prune`, will *delete* your `origin/feature` if it exists.

To do that, see [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2003505/1256452)